# cross channel parametric pooling layer in the architecture of Network in Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

While reading the paper of [Network in Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400v3.pdf), I feel confusing about some points.

The following figure shows the network architecture, looks like to me the two layers with red circle are just fully connected layer. Is that right?

[image]

Also, the authors make the following statement. But which layer is cross channel parametric pooling layer in the context of the above figure? How to understand it is equivalent with 1*1 convolution kernel.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have circled the parametric pooling layer. Those layers are **not** fully connected. In that case, the number of model parameters would be very high.

An output of a convolutional layer is an $X \times Y \times K$ tensor, where $X$ and $Y$ are width and height of the feature maps, and $K$ is their quantity (I ignore the batch dimension for simplicity). The figure shows the computation for any specific pixel location $(x,y)$ aggregated across feature maps. The same affine function followed by a ReLU non-linearity is applied to all such locations to produce a new set of feature maps. Indeed, this is a particular case of the convolutional layer where the filter size is $1 \times 1$ (conventionally, convolutional layers are “fully connected” in the feature map dimension). The number of weights is thus $2K^2$; it is independent of the feature map size.